# Wordpress Jquery Load() is loading wrong url due to permalink

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I made a template in my Wordpress theme and i have a problem with my JQuery load function to load html into div using `load.php` file that exists in the same directory as the `template.php` file but the problem is JQuery is seeing the permalink of the page instead of seeing the correct url/path to the `load.php` file.

E.g what JQuery is seeing is **mywebsite.com/permalinkhere/load?variable11=23&variable3=43** which gives 404 not found

What JQuery should see is **mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/load?variable11=23&variable3=43**

How can I solve this problem?

**Edit:**

load.php is just echo html; and it is working fine outside WordPress. Here is part of the template.php code:

```
<script>
$("#first-choice").load("load.php?variable1=load", function() {
$("#first-choice").prop("disabled", false);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your load.php?

Comment: Wordpress has it's [own way of doing ajax](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), you'd send the request to `ajaxurl`, catch it and return the rigth content, not `load()` random pages as you never how the url's are set up.

Comment: I don't think showing code from `load.php` will help. We need to see how your code is generated for the JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Java scripts you called in your HTML files are relative to that file you include Java scripts (If you use relative path).

you can use  `wp_localize_script` to set the load.php file URL.

```
wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'ajaxload', array( 'ajaxurl' => get_template_directory_uri().'/load.php' ) );
```

Then

```
var loadurl = ajaxload.ajaxurl+'?variable1=load';
$("#first-choice").load(loadurl, function() {
  // Code here ..
}
```